# How to count the mutli-dimensional arrays' value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I tried to create a table that calculating the data which stored in mutli-dimensional arrays' value and show the result by table format.

I don't know how to count the values which stored in the array's array(third level array's value.

Can I using the function to count values in the mutli-dimensional arrays' value? Hope anyone can teach me, thanks.

```
  <?php 
$itemList = array
        ("book"=>array("ID"=>"14567", 
         "name"=>array("History"=>array("American"=>12,"Europe"=>2), "SF"=>array("Space"=>32), "Chinese"=>array("kungFu"=>10))),
         "stationary"=>array("ID"=>"24547", "name"=>array("HB"=>array("ABC"=>123, "MC"=>161,"GCD"=>26)))                 
        );

   $item = "<table border=1>";
   $item .= "<td>item count(s)</td>"; 
     foreach($itemList as $key => $value){
        $item .= "<tr>";
        $item .= "<td align=center>" . 
        /*count the categories of the items(e.g. American,Europe,Space,Kungfu show          
        the result: "4")*/
         . "</td>";
        $item .= "</tr>";
     }  
   $item .= "</table>";
   echo $item;
?>
```

Comment: create another foreach loop in which add +1 for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($itemList['book']['name'] as $key => $value)
 {

    foreach ($itemList['book']['name'][$key] as $key1 => $value1) {
        $category[] = $key1;
        $value2[] = $value1;
    }

 }
```

echo count($category);

here you got the total numebr of count of your category